# How to make something in an item frame spin/rotate using a command block in Minecraft 1.19.73

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to figure out how to type a command on a command block that will let me continuously spin whatever is in an item frame.
I've tried all commands I've found for this and have had no luck. I would like for this command to work on 1.19.73.
For context, I'm trying to build a working Record Player/Turntable. I've got the design right but I need the record to actually spin in an item frame.

I'm trying to spin Music Disc 5. My coordinates are 928 61 -217.

The commands I've tried are:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,x=-1163,y=83,2=377,r=1] (ItemRotation:0b,Item:(id:"minecraft:arrow")
/testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,x=0,y=0,z=0,r=1] <(ItemRotation:0b,Item:(id."minecraft:arrow",tag: (display:(Name:"ItemNameHere")H))
/testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,x=0,y=0,z=0,r=1] (ItemRotation:0b,Item:(id:"minecraft:arrow",tag: (display:(Name:"ItemNameHere",Lore:["LoreHere"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because item frames in bedrock are blocks, not entities, and because we don't have access to the NBT data like in Java, you're for now probably stuck with this solution:

**Store the different states of the block into structures and load those structures sequentially.**

1. set up a structure block to save the item frame to a structure file.
2. rotate the item in the itemframe one step, then save it to a new structure (make sure to give it a new name).
3. repeat until all 8 states have been saved.

Then set up a repeating commandblock, followed by chain commandblocks, each with an increasing delay (say you want it to change every 4 ticks, then set the first one to a delay of 4, the second to 8, the third one to 12 etc). The repeating commandblock needs to have the total delay, so if there are 8 blocks with 4 ticks each, the repeating commandblock needs a delay of 36.

Lastly, use the [structure command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/structure) to load the various structures that you just saved in the right order at the right place.

---

*You could also make a custom entity with a custom animation that then spins the disc properly, but that's quite the additional work and is also only possible if you have file access on whatever device you're playing on.*